# Launch Terminal from Sublime Text2 Not working

Tags: xubuntu, sublime-text

I'm having Xubuntu14.04. I installed below plugin to launch Terminal.
http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/terminal

But, I'm getting below error whenever i use, "Open Terminal Here" option.

[image: The terminal terminal was not found]

I'm having below settings for both "Default" and "User":

```
{

// The command to execute for the terminal, leave blank for the OS default
// On OS X the terminal can be set to iTerm.sh to execute iTerm
"terminal": "",

// A list of default parameters to pass to the terminal, this can be
// overridden by passing the "parameters" key with a list value to the args
// dict when calling the "open_terminal" or "open_terminal_project_folder"
// commands
"parameters": []
}
```

How can I make it work? Please suggest!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Unity/Gnome, just change the line

```
"terminal": "",
```

in the **User** settings to

```
"terminal": "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal",
```

and you should be all set. If you're using KDE, the command should be `konsole`.

Good luck!